# Re asking:On the proof by Chu-Kobayashi that transformation groups are Lie groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, differential-topology

I have similar questions as[On the proof by Chu-Kobayashi that transformation groups are Lie groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d8oc.jpg) and even more, how can $Y\in\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ generate 1-parameter global transformation group of $M$ from Lemma 3, and what topologies $\mathfrak{S}$ and $\widetilde{\mathfrak{S}}$ has? I know it should be the compact-open topology.

I'm aware of the paper of Richard Palais global formulation of Lie theory of Lie transformation groups but still can't explain the action $f$ and how $Y\in\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ generate global 1-parameter global transformation group of $M$.

[image]

[image]

The answer is simply Lie-Palais Theorem, and $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ generates a 1-parameter global of transformation by existence and uniqueness of first-order differential equation on manifold ($\mathfrak{g}$ is Lie algebra consists of vector fields on the manifold).

Comment: I find it very hard to find what you're asking, especially since it seems you take the image directly from the post you link, including the highlighting of the points pertaining to the other poster's (not your) question.

Comment: I'm asking about the action $f$, and how a $Y\in\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ generates 1-parameter global of transformation, I did put the same pic since I'm asking the same questions.

Comment: You might find it easier to read the proof in Postnikov's account in Geometry VI: Riemannian Geometry.